# AddThis Sharing Events in Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, addthis

I have Google Tag Manager on the site.

I have the addthis code hardcoded into the site (i.e. not implemented via GTM):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var addthis_config = {data_ga_property: 'UA-4035505-1'};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=XXXX" async="async"></script>
```

However I am not seeing any addThis events in Google Analytics. According to their documentation, I should see events with the `eventCategory` set to `addThis`. However they aren't there. I don't know how addThis pushes events to Google Analytics (i.e. whether it is trying to utilize the `analytics.js` code on the site or uses its own method somehow). I suspect it is failing because if it is indeed trying to use `analytics.js` code it  can't since the GA tag is being fired from within GTM.

I've also tried to use the extra option `data_ga_social: true` in the `addThis` config but I am also not seeing social events pop up in Google Analytics.

Comment: Where is your GA/GTM script tag in relation to the addThis script tag?

Comment: Before. The order is: dataLayer code, GTM code, AddThis config, AddThis

Comment: This sounds more like an AddThis issue. Have you tried to troubleshoot from that side?

Comment: well there isn't, much to troubleshoot from the addThis perspective. The documenation is sparse to say the least and what little I could find I followed. The addThis buttons themselves are working fine (i.e. show up on the page and also connect correctly to the respective social sites).

Comment: Hi, I would love to see how you ended up configuring your tags manually to fire the AddThis events in GA. Care to add this as an answer, comment, or question update? That would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the addthis documentation:

["Note that AddThis doesn’t currently support Google’s Universal Analytics"](http://www.addthis.com/academy/integrating-with-google-analytics/).

This seems to be the relevant part of their widget code, and indeed it still uses the deprecated _gaq object:

```
 function x(e, t, n, r) {
        if ("facebook_unlike" != e && "google_unplusone" != e) {
            n = n || {};
            var o = n.data_ga_tracker,
                a = n.data_ga_property;
            if (a && ("object" == typeof window._gat && _gat._createTracker ? o = _gat._createTracker(a, "addThisTracker") : "object" == typeof window._gaq && _gaq._getAsyncTracker ? o = _gaq._getAsyncTracker(a) : window._gaq instanceof Array && _gaq.push([function() {
                    _ate.gat(e, t, n, r)
                }])), o && "string" == typeof o && (o = window[o]), !o && window.GoogleAnalyticsObject) {
                var i = window[window.GoogleAnalyticsObject];
                i.getAll && (o = i.getAll())
            }
            if (o && "object" == typeof o) {
                if ("more" == e || "settings" == e) return;
                var s = t || (r || {}).url || location.href,
                    c = e,
                    u = "share";
                c.indexOf("_") > -1 && (c = c.split("_"), u = c.pop(), u.length <= 2 && (u = "share"), c = c.shift()), 0 == s.toLowerCase().replace("https", "http").indexOf("http%3a%2f%2f") && (s = _duc(s));
                try {
                    n.data_ga_social && o._trackSocial && "google_plusone" != e ? o._trackSocial(c, u, r.url) : o._trackEvent ? o._trackEvent("addthis", e, s) : n.data_ga_social && "google_plusone" != e ? i("send", "social", c, u, s) : i("send", "event", "addthis", e, s)
                } catch (l) {
                    try {
                        o._initData && o._initData(), n.data_ga_social && o._trackSocial && "google_plusone" != e ? o._trackSocial(c, u, r.url) : o._trackEvent ? o._trackEvent("addthis", e, s) : n.data_ga_social && "google_plusone" != e ? i("send", "social", c, u, s) : i("send", "event", "addthis", e, s)
                    } catch (l) {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that a shame really. Universal Analytics went out of beta in April 2014, that should have been enough time for addThis to implement the relatively minor changes necessary.